# Why is there no picture showing in the background?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="Image">
<!--         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671742225244-ee282feb769d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ2ODc3NDY&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80" alt="Diagonal Stripes"> -->
    </div>
```

```
#Image {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671742225244-ee282feb769d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ2ODc3NDY&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

I've made this code and/but I don't see any image. Why is that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/objectmaybefound/pen/XWBqRdN

Comment: add dimensions / content to the div. it has no size so the image can't be seen. ( eg. `width: 200px; height: 800px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add dimensions / content to the div. it has no size so the image can't be seen. ( eg. width: 200px; height: 800px)

You may also want to have a look at `background-size`, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.php).

```css
#Image {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671742225244-ee282feb769d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ2ODc3NDY&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80");  
  background-size: contain;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
    <div id="Image">
<!--         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671742225244-ee282feb769d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ2ODc3NDY&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80" alt="Diagonal Stripes"> -->
    </div>
```

Comment: The magic word was "background-size: contain". It's solved now. I didn't even have to use height/width. I guess cause I'm using flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is two solutions:

```css
#Image {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671742225244-ee282feb769d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ2ODc3NDY&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  width:100;
  height:100;
background-size: contain;
}
img {
  width:100;
  height:100;
}
```

```html
<div id="Image">
First solution - This is not a good solution because the img could not be zoomed even using   scale:0.11;
    </div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1671742225244-ee282feb769d?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ2ODc3NDY&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80" alt="Diagonal Stripes">
<!--Second solution:Using img and this is good-->
```

Comment: The magic word was "background-size: contain". It's solved now. I didn't even have to use height/width. I guess cause I'm using flexbox.